# kubeadm join Failed to request cluster info

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have two server to work as master and work node on AWS Cloud Setup.

```
master node
  17.51.233.41
work node
  17.51.34.188
```

In master node, I success using `kubeadm init` to setup with Calico network. It report message code for me to join other node

```
kubeadm join 172.31.43.44:6443 --token XXX \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:XXX
```

But when I try to using this code to join work node, it seems cannot access to this ip port `172.31.43:6443`, and report error message below.

```
I0124 11:38:19.807720    
6665 token.go:191] [discovery] Failed to connect to API Server "172.31.43.44:6443": 
Get https://172.31.43.44:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s: 
context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

How can I connect work node to the master?

Comment: Are you on public cloud or on prem?

Comment: The Aws cloud server.

Comment: Are you able to ping form one vm to another?

Comment: Yes, I cannot talent to master 6443 port, I use ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to allow traffic from worker to master by creating application security group in AWS EC2 dashboard. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#creating-security-group) is the documentation on how to create security group for EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Master node & worker node should be reachable to each other - and should be in same subnet - example if master node having IP - 17.51.233.41/24 then worker node should be somewhere 17.51.233.X/24.